# Get facebook comments count for multiple posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that there are many questions about it, but it is not really what I want.

I have a page with multiple posts on it. Each post has its own comments count.
It was simple to get comments count of each post when I was using native website commenting system.
Now I want to use Facebook comments API. But there is a problem, how to get comments count of 20-30 posts which are loading dynamicly.

I have few ideas about that:

1) Grab all urls of that 20-30 posts. Make an async request to FB opengraph to get comments count. Parse DOM and change count values.

*But this can be slow and don't know if there is an ability to get count for a bunch of urls*

2) Prepare CRON method to grab comments count for all posts. And save info to DB.

*Not sure, how to do that. But still a variant =)*

Any ideas about that?
Would be nice to hear your variants to solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

There are already multiple answers to this at SO I think. Have a look at [How to get most liked, commented and shared posts from Facebook's API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151096/how-to-get-most-liked-commented-and-shared-posts-from-facebooks-api/24360412#24360412) to get an idea of how to pull the data on all Page feed entries...

Comment: This answer is good for page with one post, but what about page with multiple posts with their own url and comments?